# shell - Process detached by running in background and redirecting STDIN/OUT?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, root, detach

In an ssh session on a server I started some bash processes (that start other processes) in the background with `&` and redirected their stdin / stdout to file (`<dev/null >mylog.out`).

The processes are not listed under `jobs` and `ps -T` shows only one `bash` process and `ps` itself.

Most of the (child) processes are run by user `root` but are all linked to a specific TTY `pts/20`.

If I close the ssh session, will the processes and their children be sent the HUP signal or will they continue running? If yes, how could I completely detach them?

Comment: With the use of `nohup` ? But be careful because nohup redirects output in nohup.out file

Comment: you can also use screen command.

Comment: I don't know which PIDs to nohup. `ps` only shows the two processes and the other ones are running as root...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a process in the background the process will ignore the SIGHUP command.  So the process will continue to run.

Test results:

Login and run `bash` script `o.sh` in background and exit:

```
system:10.11.2.122 > o.sh &
system:10.11.2.122 > exit
```

Login back into system and check `o.sh` process:

```
system:10.11.2.122 > ps -ef | grep o.sh
root     19115     1  0 10:10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/bin/bash /root/scripts/o.sh
root     27774 20197  0 10:23 pts/2    00:00:00 grep o.sh
```

This method daemonises a running process.

With `bash`, this behavior is dependent on the `huponexit` shell option.  These, and other option settings, can be seen using the `shopt` command on CentOS/RedHat 6.7.

`huponexit` appears to be off by default on CentOS/RedHat 6.7.

A subset of the output of `shopt`:

```
histappend      off
histreedit      off
histverify      off
hostcomplete    on
huponexit       off
interactive_comments    on
lithist         off
login_shell     on
mailwarn        off
no_empty_cmd_completion off
nocaseglob      off
nocasematch     off
nullglob        off
```

So to answer your questions:

*If I close the ssh session, will the processes and their children be sent the HUP signal or will they continue running?*

That depends on your `huponexit` setting.  If `huponexit` is `off`, then *no* and process will continue to run.  Otherwise, *yes*.

*If yes, how could I completely detach them?*

Use the `nohup` command when executing the process.

```
nohup your_process &
```